# Spreadsheet Formula to Sum Values Over A if B is not in a List of Values

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have a table that looks the following:

```
|  A   | B | C |
| 40   | 1 | 1 |
| 180  | 2 | 2 |
| 34   | 1 |
| 2345 | 3 |
| 23   | 1 |
| 1    | 2 |
| 4354 | 3 |
| 2    | 2 |
| 343  | 4 |
| 2    | 2 |
| 45   | 1 |
| 23   | 1 |
| 4556 | 3 |
```

I want to get the sum of all fields in A where B is neither 1 nor 2 or any other value from colum C. This column contains the values of B where values from A should not be considered for the sum.

I do not know which values B might contain, those values are random and could grow larger, I just wanted to make the example small. My current solution is

```
{=SUMIF(B1:B13,C1:C2,A1:A13)}
```

so i can set the lines that should be excluded from the sum in column C. Unfortunately, the current solution does not solve my problem but something different -- it sums up the corresponding entries by value in C. My preferred solution would look something like

```
=SUMIF(B1:B13,"<>{1, 2}",A1:A13)
=SUMIF(B1:B13,"<>"&C1:C2,A1:A13)
```

if that were possible (it isn't). I would like to have:

- a field (with a list, for example) or column where i can put in the values of B that I do not want to be part of the sum over A.
- a method that works with Open Office as well as Excel. I prefer an OO solution.

Comment: sum the total and subtract the sum of the two.

Comment: of course that works, but i want a formula to do it as I asked. Is there a way to have a criteria like "<>{1 , 2}" at all? I cannot Google anything up :/

Comment: Can't [tag:libreoffice-calc] perform a query where you can use an aggregate sum function and a NOT IN {set}?

Comment: The problem with native worksheet formulas is that when something is not *1*, it could be *2* (and vice versa).

Comment: Is there any relevance to column D?

Comment: Actually not, I deleted it.

Comment: Yes, how to use the **not in** with a cell or a column?

Comment: Are the values in B always integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array formula so that you can multiply each value in A with a condition. That condition can be any valid Excel formula, so, for instance, you could use `MATCH` to test if the B value occurs in C:

```
=SUM((A1:A13)*ISNA(MATCH(B1:B13,$C:$C,0)))
```

The `ISNA` function returns `TRUE` when the match fails, which in a multiplication is used as a numerical value 1. `FALSE` will make the product 0.

Make sure to enter this as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: +1 thank's that solves another problem with the spreadsheet too! :) I knew that there must be a simple solution to that.